# Cannot set cookie for parent domain

Tags: node.js, express, iis

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention one important detail: even though the browser recieves it as system.client.com, the cookie is not sent on future requests to tat same backend

I have a site at system.client.com and another one for the same client at crm.client.com.

I want the users to be able to go to the system URL, log in, and have their sessions available at the CRM site.

As far as I can tell, that is very very easy. I just have to set the cookie's domain to '.client.com'

However it doesn't matter what I set (even random words, or another subdomain of system, or anything) the domain *always* arrives at my browser as "system.client.com".

(I believe this worked on my test system, but it's Saturday so I'm not at the office and can log in to check.)

I know the theory works and that both my browsers support it because I tested it with setcookie.net.

Go to a.setcookie.net, go to b.setcookie.net, from "a" set a cookie for ".setcookie.net", refresh "b" and the cookie will appear.

The one major difference between setcookie and my case is that for me, the front end's URL is 'client.com' and the backend is 'client.com:444'

So it has to be something with Express, or maybe IIS is messing with it?

I've set the cookies as a header with a string instead of using reponse.cookie() because I had no idea what else I could try. they both behaved the same way

```js
function firmarYEncriptarCookie(reponse, cookie, value, origin) {
    try {
        let token = jwt.sign({ Dato: value.toString() }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_TIME })
        let iv = crypto.randomBytes(ivlength)
        let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)
        let ciphered = cipher.update(token, inputEncoding, outputEncoding)
        ciphered += cipher.final(outputEncoding)
        let ciphertext = iv.toString(outputEncoding) + '-' + ciphered
        let tokenEncriptado = ciphertext
        let s = cookie+'='+tokenEncriptado+'; Path=/; Domain=.client.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax'
        reponse.set('set-cookie',s)
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        throw new ErrorHandler('No se pudo firmar la cookie', 500, error.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried res.cookie ? https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: I've mentioned res.cookie in the post. it is what i intend to use and what i was using. but since it didn't work, i tried setting the header directly. I decided to post the code i have right now, insted of the code i will have

Comment: check your browsers developer tools when you request the cookie there might be a hint on why cookie does not get set hence you are adding it in header

Comment: firefox show a invalid cookie error(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidCookieDomain)
chrome (brave) does not sow an error, but it shows an exclamation mark next to the cookie header (with no info)

Comment: i forgot to mention something really importan. even though the browser recieves it as system.client.com, the cookie is not sent on future requests to tat same backend

Comment: could it be cors related? maybe i've something wrong with my cors so if basically send "only allow this origin" or something like that, both browsers correct the cookie domain?

Comment: i'm also considering if ISS is messing with the headers because i use url rewrite

Comment: You can use fiddler to check if the browser is returning the cookie header. This will show you the headers and cookies sent for each request and response, so you can see if the correct domain is set and what happens to requests to the second domain.